# Which compiler to use for Koa - TSC or Babel?

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, koa, tsc

I am using koa framework of node.js. I have implemented my code using typescript. I have created .ts files for the same and I am using tsc compiler to compile it.

Should I use babel or tsc for compiling the code?

Answer (score 0):

> Before sometime, I read about babel. Now, I have a doubt wheather to use babel or tsc for compiling the code. Please suggest.

Both are excellent choices.

Babel: Main focus is transpiler 
TypeScript: In addition to be a transpiler main focus is a type checker.

## Opinion

[I prefer TypeScript for reasons covered here](https://medium.com/@basarat/typescript-won-a4e0dfde4b08)